# Why is my assignment rules not being adhered to in new profile?

Tags: permissions, rest, assignment-rules

I am using the Salesforce REST API to create Leads in my system, I have one active Lead assignment rule.

The user I have authenticated with has minimal acccess to Salesforce, allowing REST and access to the Lead object itself.

When I create a lead through a callout (in Postman), the lead fails to run through the assignment rule but I switch the user's profile to a System Administrator with access to everything the assignment rules do run.

I know there is a `Sforce-Auto-Assign` header I could assign, but by default its set to TRUE anyway. Of course for testing sake I've also manually set this to TRUE and even used the assignment rule ID but it still wasnt assigned.

I suspect there is another setting but its not clear what it is.

Comment: You'll want to set a TraceFlag on the user (Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs) to see if the rule is firing and what the result is. It may be an incorrect criteria or something else. Just because it's not assigned the way you think it should be does not mean it is not executing.

Comment: You are right, looking at the debugs the assignment rules are not matched when using one of the profiles. What doesn't make sense though is the criteria fields are identical in both records (one created for in each profile)

Comment: Can you include more info in your question, then? Maybe we'll see something.